# Fluent NHibernate - Inheritance mapping - Unmapped classes

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have the following table structure:

```
ADVERTITEMBUY    |  ADVERTITEMSELL 
Id (PK)          |  Id (PK)
Title            |  Title
...              |  ...
-------------------------------------
BIDITEMBUY            | BIDITEMSELL
AdvertItemBuy (PK/FK) | AdvertItemSell (PK/FK)
...                   | ...
```

Programatically, I'm doing this class structure:

```
public abstract class Advert : BaseEntity {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class AdvertItemBuy : Advert {
   ...
}

public class AdvertItemSell : Advert {
   ...
}

-------------------------------------------------------------

public abstract class Bid : BaseEntity {
    public Advert Advert { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class BidItemBuy : Bid {
    ...
}
public class BidItemSell : Bid {
    ...
}
```

When I go to Fluent NHibernate to map these class, I'm doing this:

```
public class BaseMapping<T> : ClassMap<T> where T : BaseEntity {
    public BaseMapping(string table, bool cacheEntities = false) {
        Schema("dbo");
        Table(string.Format("[{0}]", table));

        if (cacheEntities) {
            Cache.ReadWrite();
        }
    }
}

public class AdvertMapping<T> : BaseMapping<T> where T : Advert {
    public AdvertMapping(string tableName) : base(tableName) {
        Id(advert => advert.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();
    }
}

public class AdvertItemBuyMapping: AdvertMapping<AdvertItemBuy> {
    public AdvertItemBuyMapping() : base("AdvertItemBuy") { }
}

public class BidMapping<T> : BaseMapping<T> where T : Bid {
    public BidMapping(string tableName, string advertTable) : base(tableName) {
        CompositeKey()
            .KeyReference(bid => bid.Advert, advertTable);
    }
}

public class BidItemBuyMapping : BidMapping<BidItemBuy> {
    public BidItemBuyMapping() : base("BidItemBuy", "AdvertItemBuy") { }
}
```

Ok, I think the mapping is correctly. When I try to create a new session factory, NHibernate gives me the following error:

```
{"An association from the table [BidItemBuy] refers to an unmapped class: SYB.Engine.Entities.Advert"}
```

What am I doing wrong on this?

Thank you all!